# How minimize Signal messenger to system tray (top-right corner)?

Tags: panel, system-tray, voip

This is standard behaviour of all desktop messengers (Skype, Viber, Telegram, ..). All of them minimizes itself in system tray when <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> or close button is activated and they are running in background (instead of closing completely).

How can I force Signal messenger to behave the same way?

Comment: If you're trying to do the same thing on Windows, check out *Super User*'s [How do I minimize Signal to the system tray on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/1562696/how-do-i-minimize-signal-to-the-system-tray-on-windows) (adding this pointer because this question is ranking high for Windows search queries).

Comment: I wonder why none of the answers are accepted by the OP. Are they all crap?

Answer (score 51):

Jiří Doubravský solution worked for Gnome on Ubuntu 19.04.

Add `--use-tray-icon` option inside the `Exec` line in `/usr/share/applications/signal-desktop.desktop` from:

```
Exec=/opt/Signal/signal-desktop --no-sandbox %U
```

To:

```
Exec=/opt/Signal/signal-desktop --use-tray-icon --no-sandbox %U
```

Restarted Signal a couple times and the tray icon shows up.  Strange that this isn't enabled by default.

Comment: I'm using a different Linux (Peppermint 10), but I thought I'd tell people that this doesn't work for me. "Cannot read property 'isVisible' of undefined"

Comment: Thanks this works but signal tray icon disappears after the laptop is resumed from sleep. Is there a way to not make it disappear ?

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu 20.04, as well. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't `--no-sandbox` a bad option to put there? (exploitation easier?)

Comment: This did not work for me, but `--start-in-tray` did.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 21.04 but for some reason you have to logout and log back in for it to work.

Comment: Instead of editing the desktop file installed by the package, which will get overwritten with updates, I copy the file from `/usr/share/applications` to `~/.local/share/applications`, edit it there and run `kbuildsycoca5` (to refresh the list or programs in KDE Plasma).

Comment: Works great in Kubuntu (KDE) 22.04. I didn't even need to restart anything. Just closed the instance which was running and when I started the Signal again it added its icon in notification area. Window close now doesn't stop the messenger, but only hides the main window.

Answer (score 20):

You can use **optional arguments** to start the application

`--start-in-tray` and/or `--use-tray-icon`

**Startup launcher**:
Add both arguments.

**Desktop launcher icon**:
Add just the second one argument. In `menulibre`, search for "Signal" and change command from `"/opt/Signal/signal-desktop" %U` to `"/opt/Signal/signal-desktop" --use-tray-icon %U`

source: https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Desktop/issues/2911#issuecomment-439545459

Comment: doesn't work...

Comment: ... it probably does not work if you install Signal using Snap... just use `sudo apt install signal-desktop` instead

Answer (score 2):

A one-liner. Personally I have this saved on my desktop since Signal updates seem to to remove it.

```
sudo sed -i 's/signal-desktop --no-sandbox %U/signal-desktop --use-tray-icon --no-sandbox %U/g' /usr/share/applications/signal-desktop.desktop
```

sed is find and replace matching `signal-desktop --no-sandbox %U` and replacing with `signal-desktop --use-tray-icon --no-sandbox %U`

Comment: I use `~/.local/share/applications/` location for `.desktop` files, as this allows using Activites overview for launching modified apps.

Answer (score 2):

I propose building onto [robmsmt](https://askubuntu.com/users/713611/robmsmt)'s one-liner to account for different launch options I've encountered in the wild (without `--no-sandbox`, with lowercase `%u`, and 'empty' option `--`), probably depending on Signal version and/or distro used.

`sed -i '/^Exec/ {/--use-tray-icon/ !s/$/ --use-tray-icon/}' /usr/share/applications/signal-desktop.desktop` (Needs sudo)

This will match a line starting with `Exec` and appending `--use-tray-icon` to the end of that line *unless* the line already contains `--use-tray-icon`.

I previously suggested using [incron](https://www.linux.com/topic/desktop/how-use-incron-monitor-important-files-and-folders/) to automatically run such script when the desktop file is modified, but sadly upon closer inspection it didn't actually work as the files are not really modified but completely replaced during an upgrade. I didn't manage to get `incron` to work with that, but you might want to take a look if you're interested and more savvy. It should be safe though to run that script as a good 'ol cron job as root (`sudo crontab -e`) e.g. at reboot (adding `@reboot script.sh` to the table). It obviously doesn't take effect immediately after Signal upgrade, but will have to suffice until I figure out what's up with incron.

Answer (score 2):

To do this for the flatpak version of Signal use [flatseal](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.github.tchx84.Flatseal). With flatseal you can easily edit this flatpaks environment variables:

- SIGNAL_START_IN_TRAY
- SIGNAL_USE_TRAY_ICON

Set them to 1 to accomplish setting of above mentioned flags. Editing the flatpaks desktop file did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of editing a root owned file that gets overwritten when the package manager installs a new version of signal-desktop, I recommend to create a custom .desktop file in your home folder, and add the `--use-tray-icon` flag there. The local user-specific .desktop files should automatically take precedence over the system-wide file.

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/applications/
cp /usr/share/applications/signal-desktop.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/signal-desktop.desktop
sed -i 's/Exec=signal-desktop /Exec=signal-desktop --use-tray-icon /' ~/.local/share/applications/signal-desktop.desktop
```